# How to use form data in another MVC?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am just at the very beginning of learning rails and ruby but am already stuck.

I have created a model, a view file and a controller with a form that allows the user to enter some data. Now I am working on another MVC that makes various calculations with these data and returns the result. My problem is: I simply don't understand how I get the data entered by the user to the model that makes the calculations. I know this is a very beginner's question, but well, looks like I can't solve it alone.

Entries Model: entry.rb

```
class Entry
    include ActiveModel::Model
    attr_accessor :icao, :string
    attr_accessor :elevation, :integer
    attr_accessor :qnh, :integer
    attr_accessor :temperatur, :integer
    attr_accessor :winddirection, :integer
    attr_accessor :windspeed, :integer
    attr_accessor :basedistance, :integer
    validates_presence_of :icao
    validates_presence_of :elevation
    validates_presence_of :qnh
    validates_presence_of :temperatur
    validates_presence_of :winddirection
    validates_presence_of :windspeed
    validates_presence_of :basedistance
end
```

Entries View: new.html.erb

```
<% content_for :title do %>Flytical<% end %>
<h3>Airfield Conditions</h3>
<div class="form">
  <%= simple_form_for @entry do |form| %>
    <%= form.error_notification %>
    <%= form.input :icao, label: 'Airfield ICAO', input_html: { maxlength: 4 }, autofocus: true%> 
    <%= form.input :elevation, label: 'Airfield Elevation', input_html: { maxlength: 4 }%> 
    <%= form.input :qnh, label: 'QNH', input_html: { maxlength: 4 }%> 
    <%= form.input :temperatur, label: 'Temperatur', input_html: { maxlength: 3 }%> 
    <%= form.input :winddirection, label: 'Wind Direction', input_html: { maxlength: 3 }%> 
    <%= form.input :windspeed, label: 'Wind Speed', input_html: { maxlength: 3 }%> 
    <%= form.input :basedistance, label: 'Base Takeoff Distance at MSL', input_html: { maxlength: 4 }%> 
    <%= form.button :submit, 'Submit', class: 'submit' %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Entries Controller: entries_controller.rb

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @entry = Entry.new
  end

  def create
    @entry = Entry.new(secure_params)
    if @entry.valid?
      flash[:notice] = "Entries for #{@entry.icao} received."
      render :new
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def secure_params
    params.require(:entry).permit(:icao, :elevation, :qnh, :temperatur, :winddirection, :windspeed, :basedistance)
  end

end
```

Now for the calculations. This is the Calculation model: calc.rb
You see I tried to get the data with @entries.xxx, but obviously that did not work

```
class Calc
    include ActiveModel::Model
    def pressalt
        if @entry.qnh < 1013
            pressalt = @entry.elevation + (1013 - @entry.qnh) * 30
        else
            pressalt = @entry.elevation
        end
    end
    def densalt
        if @entry.temperatur > 15
            densalt = pressalt + (((120 * ((@entry.temperatur - (15 - @entry.elevation * 2 /1000)))  
        else
            densalt = pressalt
        end
    end
end
```

Calculation view: new.html.erb

```
<% content_for :title do %>Flytical<% end %>
<h3>Results</h3>
<p> Test result <%= @densalt %> </p>
```

Calc controller: calcs_controller.rb

```
class CalcsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @calc = Calc.new
    end
end
```

And these are my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :entries, only: [:new, :create]
  resources :calcs, only: [:new, :create]
  root to: 'visitors#new'
end
```

Honestly, I have the impression that I am missing some basic, but major points - my hope is that I am going to learn it with this project.

Comment: Why do you need another MVC for this?
What do you mean by Another MVC?

Comment: You might find the [Getting Started with Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) a useful tutorial to work through. It demonstrates this kind of logic – building a model, saving data, etc.

Comment: Thank you guys so far! I thought it might be more clearly arranged if I separated the form input from the calculation in the model, view and controller files. Would you rather recommend to do both in the same places?